# Unable to resolve sphinx-build on ArchLinux VM (installed via pacman)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, man

I'd like concise information on kernel-internal functions, structures, and macros at hand while I develop kernel modules.

I have the [Linux-kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) repo cloned on my ArchLinux VM, and I would like to create the relevant [Sphinx documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/process/kernel-docs.html#kernel-docs).

When I run `make xmldocs` top-level `linux` directory, I receive the following error:

```
sphinx-build returned an error at ./scripts/sphinx-pre-install line 317
make[1]: *** [Documentation/Makefile:137: xmldocs] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile: 1816: xmldocs] Error 2
```

When I run it from within `linux/Documentation`, I receive this:

```
make: /scripts/sphinx-pre-install: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile: 137: xmldocs] Error 127
```

Running `sphinx-build --version` says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sphinx-build", line 5, in <module>
    from sphinx.cmd.build import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sphinx'
```

I believe it has to do with how `PYTHONPATH` is being resolved. `PYTHONPATH` is empty.

```
>> import sys
>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

`sphinx` was installed at `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages` by pacman, but `python` defaults to `3.9.7`.